# Group and aggregate a DataFrame with Apache Spark and Java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the a DataFrame with the following schema loaded in Spark:

email,
first_name,
last_name,
order_id

How can I group it by email, count the records in each group and return the a DataFrame with this schema:

email,
first_name,
last_name,
order_count

Comment: You'll need to perform a traditional SQL group by on email, count(*) then perform a join on the same table to fetch the column you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a way to do it in **Scala**:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(("a","b","c",1),("a","b","c",2),("x","xb","xc",3),("y","yb","yc",4),("x","xb","xc",5))).toDF("email","first_name","last_name","order_id")

df.registerTempTable("df")

sqlContext.sql("select * from (select email, count(*) as order_count from df group by email ) d1 join df d2 on d1.email = d2.email")
```

In **Java**, considering that you already have your DataFrame created, it's actually the same code :

```
DataFrame results = sqlContext.sql("select * from (select email, count(*) as order_count from df group by email ) d1 join df d2 on d1.email = d2.email");
```

Nevertheless, and even thought this is straight-forward solution but I consider it as a bad practice because your code will be hard to maintain and evolve. A cleaner solution would be :

```
DataFrame email_count = df.groupBy("email").count();
DataFrame results2 = email_count.join(df, email_count.col("email").equalTo(df.col("email"))).drop(df.col("email"));
```

Comment: This seems like to correct answer. One question though. Using groupBy on an RDD is allegedly slow due to data shuffling. Will I have this performance penalty with the groupBy on a DataFrame too?